# Visual Studio Code: Run button shows for Python Scripts but not for Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, windows, visual-studio-code

I use Visual Studio Code for my IDE, and I typically write Python. I just installed Ruby on my Windows 10 Computer and for some reason Visual Studio Code will not give me the Option to run a ruby file.

I downloaded the extension to ruby, and it appears installed, so I don't understand why this is happening. Does Anybody know how to fix this?

[image][image]
[image]

Comment: Do note that Play button for Python files comes from the Python extension for VS Code itself, not VS Code overall.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to extensions and type ruby and install `VSCode Ruby` after that set the path `C:\Ruby27-x64\bin` in `System properties > Environment Variables > Edit Environment Variables`

Restart VS Code Editor that it that should do the trick